# Deleting temp files

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, temp

I am making a batch file that can delete all the temporary file in windows 7 so far I have got.

```
@echo off
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Apple Computer\Safari\Cache.db"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Apple Computer\Safari\Webpage Previews"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Apple Computer\Safari\LocalStorage"
del /s /f /q "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\CrashReports"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Media Player\Art Cache\LocalMLS"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Media Player\lastplayed.wpl"
del /s /f /q "%appdata%\Microsoft\Office\Recent"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\IconCache.db"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\GDIPFONTCACHEV1.DAT"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Opera\Opera"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft Corporation\Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Mail\Backup"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_32.db"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_96.db"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_256.db"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_1024.db"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_idx.db"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_sr.db"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Caches"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn\Burn"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Media Player\Transcoded Files Cache"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Device Metadata\dmrccache\downloads"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Diagnostics"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\CometNetwork\CometBird\Profiles\u4k8vhhn.default\startupCache"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\CometNetwork\CometBird\Profiles\u4k8vhhn.default\Cache"
del /q /s /f "%ChromeCache%\*.*">nul 2>&1   
del /q /f "%ChromeDataDir%\*History*.*">nul 2>&1 
del /s /f /q "%windir%\setuplog.txt"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\FixCleaner\Logs\"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\logs\"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\Logs\"
del /s /f /q "%Programdata%\AVAST Software\Persistent Data\Avast\Logs\"
del /s /f /q "%appdata%\.minecraft\crash-reports\"
del /s /f /q "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-com-dtc-runtime_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_19295908c15690f3\MSDTC.LOG"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\System32\SMI\Store\Machine\SCHEMA.DAT.LOG2"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\system32\LocalGroupAdminAdd.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\system32\Network_LLU.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\system32\Local_LLU.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\system32\InstallPackage_ETW.Log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\inf\setupapi.offline.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\Panther\UnattendGCsetuperr.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\System32\sysprep\Panther\IE\setuperr.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\System32\sysprep\Panther\IE\setupact.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\Panther\DDACLSys.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\Panther\setupact.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\Panther\UnattendGC\setupact.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen_service.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\Panther\setuperr.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\Panther\cbs.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\System32\MRT\21063288-61F8-4060-9629-9DBDD77E3242\MpGearSupport_20131019_113721117.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\System32\MRT\21063288-61F8-4060-9629-9DBDD77E3242\MpGearSupport_20131019_115612188.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\System32\Macromed\Flash\install.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\setuperr.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\debug\WIA\wiatrace.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\Performance\WinSAT\winsat.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\Logs\FlashInstall.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\debug\mrt.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\System32\MRT\BA6D0F21-C17B-418A-8ADD-B18289A02461\MpGearSupport_20131208_101543044.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\IE9_main.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\DPINST.LOG"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\msxml4-KB973688-enu.LOG"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\HPSLPSVC0007.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen_service.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\IE10_main.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\PFRO.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\Logs\"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\inf\setupapi.dev.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\SoftwareDistribution\ReportingEvents.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\setupact.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\inf\setupapi.app.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\WindowsUpdate.log"
del /s /f /q "%windir%\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\Logs\edb.log"
del /s /f /q %appdata%\.minecraft\crash-reports\*.* /s
del /s /f /q %Programdata%\AVAST Software\Persistent Data\Avast\Logs\*.* /s
del /s /f /q %windir%\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\Logs\*.* /s
del /s /f /q %windir%\logs\*.* /s
del /s /f /q %windir%\temp\*.* /s
del /s /f /q %userprofile%\Local Settings\temp\*.* /s
del /s /f /q %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\FixCleaner\Logs\*.* /s
erase /s/q/f "c:\temp"
erase /s/q/f "c:\documents and settings\administrator\recent"
erase /s/q/f "c:\documents and settings\administrator\my recent documents"
erase /s/q/f "c:\documents and settings\administrator\local settings\my recent documents"
rmdir /s/q "c:\quarantine"
erase /s/q/f "%windir%\downloaded program files"
erase /s/q/f "%windir%\recent"
erase /s/q/f "%windir%\applog"
erase /s/q/f "%windir%\desktop\*.tmp"
erase /s/q/f "c:\documents and settings\administrator\cookies"
erase /s/q/f "c:\documents and settings\administrator\local settings\history"
erase /s/q/f "c:\documents and settings\administrator\local settings\temp"
erase /s/q/f "c:\documents and settings\administrator\local settings\temporary internet files"
erase /s/q/f "c:\documents and settings\administrator\local settings\application data"
erase /s/q/f "c:\documents and settings\administrator\userdata"
erase /s/q/f "c:\documents and settings\administrator\my recent documents"
erase /s/q/f "%windir%\system32\catroot2\*.log"
erase /s/q/f "c:\documents and Settings\administrator\application data\mozilla\Profiles\default\mhy0feee.slt\cache"
erase /s/q/f "c:\documents and Settings\administrator\application data\mozilla\Profiles\default\mhy0feee.slt\cache.Trash"
erase /s/q/f "c:\documents and Settings\administrator\application data\mozilla\Profiles\default\mhy0feee.slt\cookies.txt"
erase /s/q/f "c:\documents and settings\administrator\application data\mozilla\Profiles\default\mhy0feee.slt\downloads.rdf"
erase /s/q/f "c:\documents and settings\administrator\application data\mozilla\Profiles\default\mhy0feee.slt\history.dat"
erase /s/q/f "c:\documents and settings\administrator\application data\mozilla\Profiles\default\mhy0feee.slt\bookmarks.html"
erase /s/q/f "%windir%\debug\usermode\userenv.log"
erase /s/q/f "%windir%\debug\usermode\userenv.bak"
pause
```

Can any one expand on this so it can delete more temp files or un-needed files. So I can make this a good file cleaner.

Comment: I do know what I can and cant delete and if I make an error I can copy the files from a windows installation disk.

Comment: I think that I know what I'm doing too, yet I wouldn't ever do that kind of thing (and note that _you ask others_ to contribute locations to delete!). There is little to gain and much to lose from deleting "random" files. Only because something looks like or has a name like "tmp" or "log" doesn't mean you really don't need it. Try deleting `ntuser.dat.log1` and  `ntuser.dat.log2` in your user's folder if you are in for a really good surprise. You will need the `movefile` tool for that though, since it's opened while you're logged in. _But don't tell me that I didn't warn you, afterwards._

Comment: just to let you now I am not dong this on my primary hard drive I am using a septate one to test it. so I can reinstall windows at any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by un-needed files? Also why not use the built-in `Disk Cleanup` tool by Microsoft which would do much more than required.

You need to exercise a little bit of caution since some Temp files are needed by Windows for future Windows Updates or application updates and if not present would cause the updates to fail.

```
- Compression of old files
- Temporary Internet files
- Temporary Windows files
- Downloaded program files
- Recycle Bin
- Removal of unused applications or optional Windows components
- Setup log files
- Off-line files
```

Comment: When I say temp files I just mean anything that is not needed and that can save space.

Comment: +1  In the bad old days we needed to conserve space on small hard drives, but these days you can get a single installation file that is larger than every temp file on the PC combined.  I applaud your desire to apply programming knowledge, but deleting temp files every so often is probably best left to the disk cleanup too.  Find another task that is more useful to program.

Answer (score 1):

If I was writing the code to make a new temp file cleaning utility I would also use variable names such as %temp% as with %windir%,%userprofile%,%appdata% etc.  Tools such as Cleanmgr in windows or ccleaner by piriform do a great job of cleaning up temp files. I would caution you not to change any attributes when cleaning temp files such as removing read only access etc. the results are unpleasant. Old Prefetch files and recent items are not something I saw in your batch file. Those have been brought up on other sites in other batch files such as this one http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/2015-windows-7-temp-file-cleanup-batch-file.

Answer (score 0):

I started out with a script much like this which evolved into [BleachBit](https://www.bleachbit.org). 
You asked for more cleaning rules, and with all the extensions loaded, BleachBit has several thousand cleaning rules.

BleachBit also has a command line interface and specialized cleaning methods for JSON, SQLite, ini files, etc. It's open source and extensible, typically with XML, so feel free to contribute.